# How to make forEach function JavaScript on every click to append rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add rows in the table by click, I can't resolve.Now as you can see data is appended all object key. Because I have more than 20000 objects I must create a button when is clicked to append "options(500 or 1000)" rows, and when is clicked again to append next 500 or 1000 rows etc. "data.rows" is Array of Objects, "item" is Object and "key" is Key of Object

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/columnResult',
          data: form.serialize()
        }).done(function(data) {
            data.fields.forEach(function(item) {
              $('.thead').append("<th>" + item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1).replace(/_/g, " "));
            });
            var count = 0;
            data.rows.forEach(function(item) {
              $('.tbody').append("<tr class='" + count + "'>");
              Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
                $('.' + count).append("<td>" + item[key])
              });
              count++
            });
```

Comment: when/where do you get these 20000 results ? and what exactly is the question/issue ?

Comment: i use this for columns, from database connect with expressjs. I have  a columns with 20000 rows and when is append all rows form one column at the moment it is very slow, i need help because i can't use LIMIT for results

Comment: OK so the `GET` results in your `data.rows >= 20000` and `data.field` is your column names. Now, Creating the rows with `data.rows` is slow because it's large. OK... If you want to create few at a time, why not declare a variable and set/push the array (`data.rows`) into it and then build your table by iterating every 50..100..or 500 when user clicks on some button ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative to LIMIT in SQL syntax (that I am aware of). One way around this would be to add a column to your rows with a unique ID called something like 'set_id' or 'group_id', where every 500 or 1,000 inserted rows you increment the 'set' or 'group' ID. Then you can query the database for all items with the same group id

The rows in your database would look something like this:

ID = 0, NAME = aName, VALUE 1 = aValue, VALUE 2 = bValue, GROUP_ID = 0 <- there is the 'group_id' I was talking about 
etc untill we reach item with ID 500:
ID = 500, NAME = aName, VALUE 1 = aValue, VALUE 2 = bValue, GROUP_ID = 1

You would then perform an SQL query equivalent to:

```
$group_id = $_GET['group_id'] // group id sent via ajax, which should be incremented after every button click
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE group = $group_id";
```